# Libtool: can't locate file for: -lPods-RCTMapboxGL

Tags: ios, react-native, mapbox, libtool, libtool-xcode

There is a problem at the linking stage of my React Native project. The library `libRCTMapboxGL.a` is causing this problem.

> error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -lPods-RCTMapboxGL
>
> error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -lPods-RCTMapboxGL is not an object file (not allowed in a library)

The file `libRCTMapboxGL.a` is not being created in `/Users/user/Developer/RNProject/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/` as consequence of the error with `-lPods-RCTMapboxGL`. However, the files seem to exist:

> /Users/user/Developer/RNProject/node_modules/react-native-mapbox-gl/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-RCTMapboxGL/Pods-RCTMapboxGL.debug.xcconfig
>
> /Users/user/Developer/RNProject/node_modules/react-native-mapbox-gl/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-RCTMapboxGL/Pods-RCTMapboxGL.release.xcconfig

**Pods-RCTMapboxGL is not an object file** looks strange in the error message, the content of the files is:

```
 GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) COCOAPODS=1
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public"
OTHER_CFLAGS = $(inherited) -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public"
OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -ObjC
PODS_BUILD_DIR = $BUILD_DIR
PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = $PODS_BUILD_DIR/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)
PODS_ROOT = ${SRCROOT}/Pods
```

The setup was done according this [tutorial](https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl). Firstly using CocoaPods and then I manually verified if all the settings and files are in place.

Full error log:

```
Libtool /Users/user/Developer/RNProject/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTMapboxGL.a normal x86_64
    cd /Users/user/Developer/RNProject/node_modules/react-native-mapbox-gl/ios
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only x86_64 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk -L/Users/user/Developer/RNProject/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/bobby/Downloads/mapbox-gl-ios-0.2.17 -L/Users/user/Developer/RNProject/node_modules/react-native-mapbox-gl/ios/RCTMapboxGL -filelist /Users/user/Developer/RNProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RCTMapboxGL.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTMapboxGL.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTMapboxGL.LinkFileList -lPods-RCTMapboxGL -o /Users/user/Developer/RNProject/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTMapboxGL.a

error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -lPods-RCTMapboxGL
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -lPods-RCTMapboxGL is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
```

Comment: did you try `pod install` inside your project dir?

Comment: yes and it installed correctly... I checked the settings manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I used `pod init` inside the MapboxGL directory, which created the extra files. Removing the generated files solved the problem.